# Windows 10 - When combining MBR and GPT drives, does this affect boot priority?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, mbr, gpt

**Situation**
I have three drives in my computer. An SSD and two HDDs for storage (let's call them HDD1 and HDD2). My operating system is installed on the SSD. HDD1 has served me well for 7+ years and is slowly declining so I bought HDD2 as a replacement. I have them both hooked up so I can copy files. When installing HDD2, `Disk Management` asked me if I wanted either MBR and GPT. I was unfamiliar with the concept but after some Google searches found out GPT is more modern. So now the SSD and HDD1 are MBR and HDD2 is GPT.

**Problem**
After plugging in HDD2, the Windows installation cannot be found when booting up. Every time I start the PC I have to use the boot menu of the UEFI (picture 1). This shows my SSD and when selected starts Windows 10. I want the SSD to have the highest boot priority of course. When I go the advanced settings of the UEFI (picture 2), I can see all drives as storage but can only choose HDD2 or the optical drive when selecting boot priority. **Do GPT drives have a higher priority and how do I give the highest prioity to my SSD drive?**
[image: Boot menu of UEFI]
[image: Advanced menu of UEFI]

**Steps taken**
When placing HDD2 I decided to clean the inside of my computer. When putting things back into place, I put SATA cables in different positions. Then used `Disk Management` to initialise HDD2 and make a simple volume (the only option available) and HDD2 was ready for use. When I started the PC again later the problem started.

**My set-up**

- SSD (TS120GSSD220S), holds the OS, MBR
- HDD1 (Hitatchi HDS721010CLA332), 1TB, MBR
- HHD2 (Toshiba HDWD 120), 2TB, GPT
- Asus Fatal1ty Z170 motherboard (for the UEFI)

---

If anything is unclear, please let me know. I'm a bit new to this area of computers

Answer (score 1):

No. Boot order is decided by the motherboard. You can choose to prefer legacy or UEFI. You can also pick HDD order.

Please read your manual:
https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Fatal1ty%20Z170%20Gaming%20K4/?cat=Manual

Comment: I followed the instructions in the manual and it won't let me pick the SSD either. I can only pick HDD2 or the optical drive